# pdfwriter not wrting to file after deployment in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, itext

I'm done with a project which creates PDF documents and writes it to file which worked fine so far. But it doesn't work after I've built the project in visual studio and installed it.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
// create document
Document doc1 = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(name + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Which error message appears? Please check/debug what is inside `name`.

Comment: What reference are you using for the PdfWriter? I am assuming iTextsharp of PdfSharp. If so, are you including the referenced dll's in your installation package, or are they located in the folder with with your installed project?  Also add a try/catch around the PdfWriter statement so you can see if any type of error is occuring.